# When is the next Moderator Election?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderators, election

When is the nest moderator election? Both previous elections were held in February, so it seems that the next one is due now.

Comment: Worth noting that previously-very-active moderator @rfusca got a new job and had to step back from the previous level of  attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An election is scheduled in about 5 months — https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/3